# Can a gaussian pulse be a pure tone?

Tags: signal-processing

I was given a signal dataset, and I was told it is a gaussian pulse and a pure tone. I am unsure how this is related as when I read about this two terms, there are differences in them. so can a gaussian pulse be a pure tone too?

Comment: I'm thinking that a signal with a pure tone would be a square wave with an infinitesimally narrow width. Thus there can't really be a "pure" tone (e.g 10.0000... kilohertz) since it isn't possible to generate a signal with an infinitesimally small frequency width.  So you have to temper such a question with some required precision.

Answer (score 0):

The Fourier transform of a Gaussian is also a Gaussian, but the spectrum of a pure tone is a single frequency, which can be represented by a [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

OTOH, a perfectly pure tone is eternal, so the spectrum of a real pure tone of finite duration has a finite width, and it's certainly feasible for that spectrum to be Gaussian.

Comment: so what you're saying is only real pure tone can be gaussian and perfect pure tone can't have it? 

Just to make sure, gaussian pulse is a short pulse right?